# Setting cookie_httponly in zend framework doesn't work

Tags: php, zend-framework2, session-cookies, cookie-httponly

I want to enable httponly cookies in my zend based application. In order to do so, I added below line in application.config.php

```
'cookie_httponly' => true
```

to existing session_config array and it looks like below

```
'session_config' => [
    // Set the session and cookie expiries to 15 minutes
    'cache_expire' => 1800,
    'cookie_lifetime' => 1800,
    'cookie_httponly' => true
],
```

But it doesn't work. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

See the documentation https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.4/en/modules/zend.session.manager.html

And put your config under the line `'name' => 'myapp',`